# How to filter out only the number part (800000010627, 800000010040 and so on) from a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am fairly new to Python scripting. My problem statement is: My 'List' looks something like below. I want to take out only the 'num' part (800000010627, 800000010040 and so on). I tried few techniques but no avail. Can anybody help?

List:

```
[b'div-num-expr::060-800000010627', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010040', b'div-num-expr::060-800000011128', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010734', b'div-num-expr::060-800000013939', b'div-num-expr::060-800000014595']
```

Comment: What techniques did you try and what were the results

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ] and [ask].

Comment: if all the numbers are at the end of the bytes and is exactly 12 digits long you can just do `[item[-12:] for item in MY_LIST]`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen - That works as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way: just cut the needed part from your *bytes*:

```
only_numbers = [item[18:] for item in initial_list]
```

This expression will create a new list named *only_numbers* with numbers extracted from original list items. Note that this method simply omits the first 17 symbols, so, if prefix part of your initial data will change in length this method may fail miserably.

If that prefix (div-num-expr::060) changes you will need to harness the power of regular expressions.

You can read more about regexes in python in the [official documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html?highlight=regular)

Answer (score 0):

```
your_list=[b'div-num-expr::060-800000010627', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010040', b'div-num-expr::060-800000011128', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010734', b'div-num-expr::060-800000013939', b'div-num-expr::060-800000014595']
list_res=[]
for item in your_list :
     elm=item.split('div-num-expr::060-')[1] 
     list_res.append(elm)
print list_res
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check it out

l = [b'div-num-expr::060-800000010627', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010040', b'div-num-expr::060-800000011128', b'div-num-expr::060-800000010734', b'div-num-expr::060-800000013939', b'div-num-expr::060-800000014595']

filter = []

for eve in l:
    eve = str(eve)

```
start = eve.rfind("-") + 1

filter.append(eve[start:-1])
```

print(filter)